# Will drawables in drawable-tvdpi scale down?

Tags: android

If you put drawables in /drawables directory they will be scaled and if you want specific drawables for different densities you need to put them in specific directory (/drawables-hdpi, /drawables-mdpi etc.)

But if I have drawables only in /drawable-tvdpi will they scale down/up automaticly for ither densities?

Comment: Why don't you just try this? It would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they'll scale, so if you put a 133 x 133px drawable in the `tvdpi` folder, it'll be 100px on `mdpi`, 150px for `hdpi`, and so on.

There's more information on the [Android Developers - Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page, but in general you can get away with just putting drawables in the `tvdpi` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they will, Android always picks the best available image inside your directories, i.e. if you have an mdpi phone, and two resource types, hdpi and xhdpi, it will try to pick the one immediately above the requested density (hdpi) instead of the bigger one, because it correctly assumes it' going to be enough. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

However why not try it for yourself using [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com)? It's an Android simulator that runs pretty well. It's still in beta, but has served me well.